# How to know the speed of internet in ios programmatically

Tags: ios

I am developing the application in which every things depends on internet.my Requirement is that when the speed of internet is low,app should display alert to user that "your internet speed is low, that's why this feature is not available to you."

I want to know that is there any feature available in ios from which we can know that our internet connection is low or speed of internet, I have found 2-3 answers about this but not get any feasible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic call to know whether the Internet connection is fast or slow. There's only one solution - transfer data and time how long it takes to transfer a certain amount of data.

The problem is that the next chunk of data can be much slower, much faster, or about the same.

So you really need some sort of threshold where if the app is unable to transfer at least X number of bytes in Y seconds, then you stop the transfer and alert the user.

In other words, there's no simple way to ask "Is the connection fast or slow?".